# javascript function that takes array as input, increases each array element by 1 and returns new array with increased values not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm totally new to javascript. I'm learning how to write functions for the first time and I'm stuck with this one. Please can you help me figure out why my for loop is only looping on the first element of the array and not the others.

Thank you for your help.

See code:

I'm trying to write a function that takes as input an array of numbers and returns a new array that contains each number from the input array, increased by one.

```
function incrementEach (myArray) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(myArray + 1);
        return newArray;
    };
};
var nuArray = incrementEach ([23, 34, 56, 67]);
log (nuArray);


The result I get after running this code is: '[24]'
```

Only the first element in the array is increased and printed. Something must be wrong with my loop but I can't figure it out. Please help me!

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting the same result. Is there something else I can try?                                                                                                                         function incrementEach (myArray) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(myArray[i] + 1);
        return newArray;
    };
};

var nuArray = incrementEach ([23, 34, 56, 67]);
log (nuArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems:

1. In your newArray.push call, you're pushing the entire array + 1 instead of the individual item + 1.
2. You're returning within your loop, which means it is not a loop at all and only gets run once.

Here is your code with fixes in place:

```
function incrementEach (myArray) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(myArray[i] + 1);
    };
    return newArray;
};
var nuArray = incrementEach ([23, 34, 56, 67]);
log(nuArray);
```

You could also use the map function to do this with much less code:

```
var nuArray = [23, 34, 56, 67].map(function(item) {
    return item + 1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Gabriel. you hit the nail on the head. If I want to display the array elements without the array bracket [ ], how do I do that?

Comment: @ChichiUkomadu you can call the join function - nuArray.join(', ');

Comment: Thank you. Lastly, how do I compare two elements in an array to see if they match?

Comment: You can do that using nuArray[0] === nuArray[1]

Comment: what if I don't know the index number for the array elements and I want to use a var like i, what will that look like.

Comment: I think you should ask the new question for that one… And be specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the element from the array:

```
newArray.push(myArray[i] + 1);
```

Comment: Hello JordanHendrix, thank you so much for your response.
I tried it but I'm still getting the same result. Is there something else I can try? function incrementEach (myArray) { var newArray = []; for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { newArray.push(myArray[i] + 1); return newArray; }; }; var nuArray = incrementEach ([23, 34, 56, 67]); log (nuArray);

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the array itself not the item being looped.

use `newArray.push(myArray[i] + 1);` instead of `newArray.push(myArray + 1);` inside the loop

Also, the `return` statement should be outside the for loop

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/txguf1fu/)

Comment: Hello Muhammad, thank you so much for your response. I did that and i'm still getting the same result.

Comment: @ChichiUkomadu Updated the answer with Demo

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
function incrementEach (myArray) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    newArray.push(myArray[i] + 1); // i-th element
  }
  return newArray; // Return at the end
}
```

However, it would be simpler like this:

```
[23, 34, 56, 67].map(n => n+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr
function incrementEach (myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i] += 1
    };
    return myArray
};
arr = incrementEach([23, 34, 56, 67]);
log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best use case for `.map()`. Which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
var increased = [1, 2, 3].map(function(item, index) {
    return item + 1;
});
```

A function could look like:

```
function increaseValues(arr, amount) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        return item + amount;
    });
}

// increase array values by 5
increaseValues([1,2,4], 5);
```